# add clear cache option in react native app

Tags: react-native

I have a problem in react native app I want to add clear cache option in react native app for users to clear app cache when they want to clear basically my app is wallpapers app.

Answer (score 2):

For RN 0.60 and above, I am using yarn add [oa-react-native-clear-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oa-react-native-clear-cache) or npm install [oa-react-native-clear-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oa-react-native-clear-cache)

usage:

import ClearCache from 'oa-react-native-clear-cache'

```
ClearCache.getAppCacheSize((value, unit) => {
  console.log("cache size", value, unit) // check size
  ClearCache.clearAppCache(() => {})  // clear cache  
})
```

Comment: It's working on RN 0.64+ nicely

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-clear-app-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clear-app-cache) to do this

install with:
`npm install --save react-native-clear-app-cache`

Link with:
`react-native link react-native-clear-app-cache`

Use as follow:

```
import clearCacheModuleObj from '
react-native-clear-app-cache '

[...]

clearCacheModuleObj.clearAppCache()

[...]
```

Also, i didn't used this module so maybe this doesn't work.
Debugging has to be made.